# React-Redux: How to ensure that multiple fetch requests are all successfully made before an action is dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following code:

category-arrows.component.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { increaseCategoryRank, decreaseCategoryRank, fetchCategoryRanks } from '../../redux/menu/menu.actions';
import './category-arrows.styles.scss';

class CategoryArrows extends Component {

    render() {

        const { category } = this.props;
        const categoryClicked = true;

        return (
            <div className="arrows-container">
                <div className="up-arrow" onClick={
                    () => {
                        this.props.increaseCategoryRank(category, categoryClicked)

                        this.props.fetchCategoryRanks(this.props.menu);    
                }}></div>
                <div className="category-rank">
                    <p>{category.rank}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="down-arrow" onClick={
                    () => {
                        this.props.decreaseCategoryRank(category, categoryClicked)

                        this.props.fetchCategoryRanks(this.props.menu);                   
                }}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    menu: state.menu
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { increaseCategoryRank, decreaseCategoryRank, fetchCategoryRanks } )(CategoryArrows);
```

menu.actions.js:

```
import { apiUrl, apiConfig } from '../../util/api';
import { INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS } from './menu.types';

export const decreaseCategoryRank = (category, categoryClicked) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, category, categoryClicked })       
}

export const increaseCategoryRank = (category, categoryClicked)  => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, category, categoryClicked })
}

export const fetchCategoryRanks = menu => async dispatch => {
    console.log("Printing menu (fetch category ranks)");
    console.log(menu);

    menu.map(async (category) => {

        console.log("PRINTING CATEGORY");
        console.log(category.name);
        console.log(category.rank);

        const options = {
            ...apiConfig(),
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(category)
        }
        const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/category/${category._id}`, options)
        let data = await response.json()
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("It got sent")
        } else {
            alert(data.error)
        }
    });

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS, menu });

}
```

menu.types.js:

```
export const INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK = "INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK";
export const DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK = "DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK";
export const FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS = "FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS";
```

menu.reducer.js:

```
// import INITIAL_STATE from './menu.data';
import { INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS } from './menu.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = []


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {
            console.log("Went into increase category rank");

            if(action.categoryClicked === false) {
                return state;
            }

            const menuArray = [...state];

            var index = menuArray.map(category => category._id).indexOf(action.category._id);

            //if it's the first element in array it won't move up
            if(index === 0) {
                return state;
            } else {
                const temp = menuArray[index];
                menuArray[index] = menuArray[index - 1];
                menuArray[index - 1] = temp;


                var newrank = 0;

                menuArray.forEach(category => {
                     category.rank = newrank++;
                });


                return menuArray;
            }

        }
        case DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {
            console.log("Went into decrease category rank");

            if(action.categoryClicked === false) {
                return state;
            }

            const menuArray = [...state];

            console.log(menuArray);

            var index = menuArray.map(category => category._id).indexOf(action.category._id);

            //if it's the last element in the array, it won't move down
            if(index === menuArray.length - 1) {
                return state;
            } else {
                const temp = menuArray[index];
                menuArray[index] = menuArray[index + 1];
                menuArray[index + 1] = temp;


                var newrank = 0;

                menuArray.forEach(category => {
                    category.rank = newrank++;
                });


                return menuArray;
            }
        }
        case FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In my CategoryArrows component, clicking on the `up-arrow` div dispatches the `increaseCategoryRank` action followed by the `fetchCategoryRanks` action. Clicking `down-arrow` div dispatches the `decreaseCategoryRank` action followed by the `fetchCategoryRanks` action.

The `increaseCategoryRank` and `decreaseCategoryRank` actions changes the ranks of categories that are in the Redux state. The `fetchCategoryRanks` action, takes the menu array from the state, and sends data about the modified categories to the server through making fetch requests.

One issue that I am facing in my application is that the `increaseCategoryRank` or `decreaseCategoryRank` actions can dispatched be again (through clicking on either arrow div) before all of the fetch requests have been sent in `fetchCategoryRanks`. This results in incorrect information being sent to the server, which is then saved in a database.

I want my code to not allow the `increaseCategoryRank/decreaseCategoryRank` action to be dispatched again unless all of the fetch requests have successfully been sent to the server in the `fetchCategoryRanks` action.

However, I am not sure how to check whether all of the requests have been sent before the `increaseCategoryRank/decreaseCategoryRank` actions are dispatched. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a "pending requests" state that you can block on could help.

`menu.reducer.js` - Update state slice to hold menu array and isPending flag, add new  fetch category ranks success action type

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  menus: [],
  isPending: false // <-- add new pending flag to state slice
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {
      console.log("Went into increase category rank");

      if (action.categoryClicked === false) {
        return state;
      }

      const menuArray = [...state];

      var index = menuArray
        .map(category => category._id)
        .indexOf(action.category._id);

      //if it's the first element in array it won't move up
      if (index === 0) {
        return state;
      } else {
        const temp = menuArray[index];
        menuArray[index] = menuArray[index - 1];
        menuArray[index - 1] = temp;

        var newrank = 0;

        menuArray.forEach(category => {
          category.rank = newrank++;
        });

        return { ...state, menus: menuArray };
      }
    }
    case DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {
      console.log("Went into decrease category rank");

      if (action.categoryClicked === false) {
        return state;
      }

      const menuArray = [...state];

      console.log(menuArray);

      var index = menuArray
        .map(category => category._id)
        .indexOf(action.category._id);

      //if it's the last element in the array, it won't move down
      if (index === menuArray.length - 1) {
        return state;
      } else {
        const temp = menuArray[index];
        menuArray[index] = menuArray[index + 1];
        menuArray[index + 1] = temp;

        var newrank = 0;

        menuArray.forEach(category => {
          category.rank = newrank++;
        });

        return { ...state, menus: menuArray };
      }
    }
    case FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS:
      return { ...state, isPending: true }; // <-- set true when fetching ranks
    case FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS_COMPLETE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isPending: false, // <-- clear isPending to unblock UI
        menus: [...state.menus, action.menu], // Wasn't sure about this menu the fetchCategoryRanks function dispatches when complete
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

`menu.actions.js` - dispatch an action that the fetch requests are being made, and dispatch the fetch completion action when finished

```
export const fetchCategoryRanks = menu => async dispatch => {
  console.log("Printing menu (fetch category ranks)");
  console.log(menu);

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS }); // <-- trigger isPending to block UI

  menu.map(async category => {
    console.log("PRINTING CATEGORY");
    console.log(category.name);
    console.log(category.rank);

    const options = {
      ...apiConfig(),
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(category)
    };
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/category/${category._id}`, options);
    let data = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("It got sent");
    } else {
      alert(data.error);
    }
  });

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS_COMPLETE, menu });
};
```

`category-arrow.component.jsx` - map `isPending` to props and check before dispatching redux actions

```
class CategoryArrows extends Component {
  render() {
    const { category, isPending, menu } = this.props;
    const categoryClicked = true;

    return (
      <div className="arrows-container">
        <div
          className="up-arrow"
          onClick={() => {
            if (!isPending) {
              this.props.increaseCategoryRank(category, categoryClicked);
              this.props.fetchCategoryRanks(menu);
            }
          }}
        />
        <div className="category-rank">
          <p>{category.rank}</p>
        </div>
        <div
          className="down-arrow"
          onClick={() => {
            if (!isPending) {
              this.props.decreaseCategoryRank(category, categoryClicked);
              this.props.fetchCategoryRanks(menu);
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isPending: state.menu.isPending,
  menu: state.menu.menus,
});
```